# Access VBA: Get difference in value between current and previous record

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, report

I have made report based on query according to this link:

http://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/max_query2.php

It gives me list of records with values:

(primaryKey)
ID.......FirstNum....SecNum.....Diameter.....Owner
1........100200.......01...............150..............Peter
2........100200.......02...............138..............Peter
 
3........100300.......07...............112..............John

Query sorts records in descending order by Diametral. I want make new column which will count difference between first and second record, then between third and second and so on. Like this:

(primaryKey)
ID.......FirstNum....SecNum.....Diameter.....DiffDiametral.....Owner
1........100200.......01...............150.......................................Peter
2........100200.......02...............138.............12......................Peter
 
3........100300.......07...............112.............26.....................John

What should I write into RowSource or DataSource for DiffDiametral to get these values? How can I avoid error for first line, where is not previous value which I want substract from?

I tried to solve it according to this link:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/101081/en-us
but I did not solve it. Simply I dont know how I can refer previous value of Diameter to count difference.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your information, a subquery should do it. Just substitute your actual table name for tblDiameters.

```
SELECT C.ID, C.FirstNum, C.SecNum, C.Diameter, C.Owner, 
   (SELECT TOP 1 P.Diameter  
   FROM tblDiameters AS P  
   WHERE P.Diameter < C.Diameter  
   ORDER BY P.Diameter DESC ) 
    - C.Diameter AS DiffDiameter
FROM tblDiameters AS C
```

Comment: Is it possible to refer previous record with DLookUp() function?

Comment: @Seeter
Not DLookup, but DMax, but would probably be slower.
What is the problem with using the subquery?